# Reactjs POST mixing PATH

Tags: reactjs, axios, crud

I turn into a little issue:

here is my issue,
my react app on post request mix front path and API path

front:
`http://localhost/USER_ROLE/UID/add-article`
api path:
`api/private/articles`

so in the navigator, the request made for my post is
`http://localhost/USER_ROLE/UID/add-article/api/private/articles`

in AddArticlePage.js:

```js
const AddArticlePage = ({}) =>{

const [success, setSuccess] = useState(null)
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

const creationHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newArt = {...};

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    axios
      .post("api/private/articles", newArt, config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setSuccess("article created");
        setTimeOut(()=>{setSuccess(null)}, 5000)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setError("nope...");
        setTimeOut(()=>{setError(null)}, 5000)
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {success ? <popup message={success} /> : <popup message={error } />}
      <ArticleForm trigger={creationHandler} />
    </>
  )
}
```

if you wonder why the path isn't the full path, it is because I add a proxy with the local IP for the backend in the package.json:
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",

do you have any idea?

Comment: add `/` at the start: `/api/private/articles`

Answer (score 0):

you are using axios.post("api/private/articles", newArt, config) hence added localhost url before api.
we have 2 steps check below

1. API base url is http://127.0.0.1:5000/ so need to set like .

   ```
   const base_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
    axios.post(`${base_url}/api/private/articles`, newArt, config)
   ```
2. Add below code on your package.json file

   "proxy": { "/services": {
   "target": "127.0.0.1:5000",
   "changeOrigin": true,
   "pathRewrite": { "^/services": "" }
   }},

close terminal and `npm start`

Comment: the `base_url` is already set in the package.json with the `proxy` line. It was into the description, read carefully bro

Comment: can you share json file where set ?

Comment: ```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {...},
}
```

Comment: the whole app works fine GET, PATCH, DELETE but the happen only for the POST

Comment: answer updated check may be help for you.

Comment: nope sorry, your answer did not help me. :-( sorry previous message wasn't accurate...

Answer (score 0):

as @GabrielePetrioli said just a `/` before API path

looks like the `/` in the proxy line into the package.json isn't recognized in this case.

at least for the POST...